# print records using awk with array

Tags: arrays, bash, awk

```
/stu/class/sub/med/science score: 100 name: A status: Pass Roll: 12
/stu/class/sub/med/hist  score: 75 name: B status: Pass Roll: 13
/stu/class/sub/med/comp score: 96 name: C status: Pass Roll: 14
/stu/class/sub/med/geo score: 40 name: D status: Fail Roll:15
/stu/class/sub/med/mat score: 100 name: D status: Pass Roll:16
```

I have above details in a file say "input.txt" and i want to print the $1 if those of scored greater than 95. In this case, I should get the following output.

```
science score: 100
comp score: 96
mat score: 100
```

Can someone help me to code this. I am trying to use awk with array. So far i have done this, but did not yet complete.

```
declare -A list
i=1
while read line; do
list[$i]=$(echo $line | awk '{print $3}')
((i++));
done < input.txt
for i in "${list[@]}"; do
echo "$i";
if ...
done
```

Answer (score 2):

It is as simple as this:

```
awk '$3 > 95 {sub(/.*\//,"",$1); print $1, $2, $3}' test.txt
```

`awk` separates lines by spaces by default. The third field is the actual score, so this is where you check for a value greater than 95. To get the output you stated, you have to print the first three fields, and not only the first (which would be the path only).

**Update:** Thanks to @jaypal for the comment on how to remove the path.

Note however, that this only works if you don't have any spaces in your path- and filenames.

Comment: How should I print as below by simply excluding all /             science score: 100
comp score: 96
score: 100

Comment: @user3834663, if this is a new requirement, update your question.

Comment: @user3834663 Use `sub` to remove it. `awk '$3 > 95 {sub(/.*\//,"",$1); print $1, $2, $3}'` or `split` it and pick the last entry `awk '$3 > 95 {n=split($1,a,/\//); print a[n], $2, $3}'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
awk '{if ($3 > 95) print $1, $2, $3;}' < input.txt
```

Redirection is optional therefore, the following will work as well.

```
awk '{if ($3 > 95) print $1, $2, $3}' input.txt
```

Comment: The way that awk works (`condition { action }`) means that an `if` is completely redundant here.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'[/ ]+' '$8>95{print $6, $7, $8}' file
science score: 100
comp score: 96
mat score: 100
```

Comment: That would depend on the number of `/` , which would work with the sample, but not if the number of / could be variable. An alternative would be to use `-F'.*/| +'` and use $2, $3 and $4.

Comment: That would depend on whether or not a `/` can be present at other places in some lines. All we have to go on is the posted sample input and hope the OP has shown us the things that vary in the formatting of the lines. He showed the same number of slashes in the first field of every line so I expect that's always the case and if it's not the OP can always tell us and update their question with more representative input.